# A way to store a method in a variable?

Tags: c#, variables, methods

Hello I am new to programming.
Basically I need to store a method A from class A in variable A from class B inside a method from class B but I cannot seem to find a way.

To give an example:
Class A

```
public void methodA()
{
*method*
}
```

Class B

```
Delegate variableA; //I believe using Delegate is wrong

public void methodB();
{
variableA = ClassA.methodA();
}
```

Then in Class B there would be another method that will utilize the variable with the stored method.

```
public void methodC();
{
variableA;
}
```

This isn't the exact code I have but this is basically the gist of it. Any help is appreciated :)

Edit: Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Use `Action` e.g.

Comment: You can use `Action` and `Func` delegates to store methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassA` definition:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public void MethodA() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

`ClassB` definition:

```
public class ClassB
{
    private Action VariableA { get; set; }

    public void MethodB(ClassA classA)
    {
        VariableA = classA.MethodA;
    }

    public void MethodC()
    {
        VariableA();
    }
}
```

`Program` definition:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    ClassB classB = new ClassB();
    classB.MethodB(classA);
    classB.MethodC();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection:

```
public class A
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MethodA");
    }

    public static void StaticMethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StaticMethodA");
    }
}

public class B
{
    MethodInfo mv = typeof(A).GetMethod("MethodA");
    MethodInfo smv = typeof(A).GetMethod("StaticMethodA");

    public void CheckA(bool useStatic)
    {
        if (useStatic) smv.Invoke(null, null);
        else mv.Invoke(new A(), null);
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.CheckA(true);
        b.CheckA(false);
    }
}
```

See [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
public class Test
   {
       private Action<int> hiddenMethod = new Action<int>((i) =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine(i);
       });

       public void PublicMethod(int i)
       {
           hiddenMethod(i);
       }
   }
```

And using it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.PublicMethod(21);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```